# Регулярное выражение для многоязычности

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Есть шаблон. В нём есть записи типа `{_LANG_}{ru}сутки{en}day{_LANG_}`. Есть переменная `$slln`, в которой содержится выбранный язык. Моя задала заменить всю запись на текст выбранного языка. Например если `$slln='en'`, то вся запись должна быть заменена на `day`. Я так понял, что одной командой это не сделать, так что делаю так:

`preg_match_all("/{_LANG_}(.*){_LANG_}/",$overall_output,$mt);`

Тут результат следующий:

```
$mt = Array (
    [0] => Array (
            [0] => {_LANG_}{ru}сутки{en}day{_LANG_}
            [1] => {_LANG_}{ru}неделю{en}week{_LANG_}
            [2] => {_LANG_}{ru}месяц{en}month{_LANG_}
            [3] => {_LANG_}{ru}все время{en}all time{_LANG_}
        )

    [1] => Array (
            [0] => {ru}сутки{en}day
            [1] => {ru}неделю{en}week
            [2] => {ru}месяц{en}month
            [3] => {ru}все время{en}all time
        )
)
```

Вопрос в том, как бы из `$mt[1]` вынуть все значения, что бы получить что-то вроде:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
            [ru] => сутки
            [en] => day
        )
    [1] => Array (
            [ru] => неделю
            [en] => week
        )
    ...

)
```

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо, но я догадался сделать ещё лучше. Учитывая, что язык я уже знаю заранее и в тексте могут так же встречаться фигурные скобки и переносы тоже, то получилось следующее:

```
$rl='en';
preg_match_all("/{_LANG_}.*?{".$rl."}(.*?)(?:{[a-zA-Z]+}.*?|){_LANG_}/s",$overall_output,$mt);
```

Результат:

```
$mt = Array (
    [0] => Array (
            [0] => {_LANG_}{en}day {скобки}{ru}сутки{_LANG_}
            [1] => {_LANG_}{ru}неделю{en}week{_LANG_}
            [2] => {_LANG_}{ru}месяц{en}month{_LANG_}
            [3] => {_LANG_}{ru}все время{en}all time{_LANG_}
        )
    [1] => Array (
            [0] => day {скобки}
            [1] => week
            [2] => month
            [3] => all time
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Если условиться, что текст не содержит фигурных скобок, то можно воспользоваться таким [регулярным выражением](http://regex101.com/r/qW0uH3):

```
/(?<=({ru}|{en}))([^{]+)/g
```

Например:

```
function tr($text, $lang) 
{
    if (preg_match_all('/(?<=({[\w]{2}}))([^{]+)/', $text, $matches)) {
        $lang = '{' . strtolower($lang) . '}';
        foreach ($matches[1] as $key => $_lang) {
            if (strtolower($_lang) == $lang) {
                return $matches[2][$key];
            }
        }
    }

    return '';
}

echo tr('{ru}сутки{en}day', 'ru') . "\n"; // сутки
echo tr('{ru}сутки{en}day', 'en') . "\n"; // day
echo tr('{ru}сутки{en}day', 'fr') . "\n"; //
```

Если же результат нужен именно в том виде, который вы указали, то:

```
function trArr(array $texts) {
    $translates = [];
    foreach ($texts as $key => $text) {
        if (preg_match_all('/(?<=({[\w]{2}}))([^{]+)/', $text, $matches)) {
            foreach ($matches[1] as $key2 => $lang) {
                $translates[$key][trim($lang, '{}')] = $matches[2][$key2];
            }
        }
    }

    return $translates;
}
```